# C++ How to return array of objects from a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, oop, object

recently I have started learning c++, so I'm trying to make a simple grade calculator using my base knowledge (I'm already good with Javascript so i know the basics of programming).

So in this case, I had to return an array of objects from a function call so i can use it later in the program, but I just couldn't find the right way to do so.

So basically i want to return `subArr` from the `getInput` function, but I couldn't do that due to my basic knowledge in the language. I tried googling but didn't find any simple solution.

Here is the code and hope it is simple:

```cpp
//the Subject class:
class Subject {
    public:
        string name;
        float grade;
        int factor;
        
        Subject(){};
        
        Subject(string x, float y, int z){
            name = x;
            grade = y;
            factor = z;
        }
};

//get Input function declaration
Subject getInput(int num){
    
    //array of objects of type "Subject"
    Subject subArr[num];
    
    //a for loop to assign the array's elements
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        string name;
        float grade;
        int factor;
        
        cout << "what is the name of subject " << i+1 <<"? "<<endl;
        cin >> name;
        
        cout << "what is the grade of subject " << i+1 << "? "<<endl;
        cin >> grade;
        
        cout << "what is the factor of subject " << i+1 << "? "<<endl;
        cin >> factor;
        
        subArr[i]=Subject(name, grade, factor);
    };
    
    //trying to return the subArr at last
    return subArr;
};

//main function
int main(){
    //get the number of subjects
    int numOfSubjects;
    cout << "how many subjects are there? ";
    cin >> numOfSubjects;
    
    //trying to receive the subArr from getInput call
    Subject subArr = getInput(numOfSubjects);
    
};
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector<Subject>`

Comment: `Subject subArr[num];` is not valid c++, since `num` is a run-time value. Just use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @cigien but i need the `num` to initialize the array's size, also can u give me a code example of using std::vector? i'm a newbie, thanks

Comment: it gives me this error:
`could not convert 'subArr' from 'Subject [num]' to 'std::vector<Subject`

Comment: Thousands on the net. [This one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is from a solid documentation site you should bookmark.

Comment: @WhozCraig oh, nvm, you meant make the subArr a vector and return it, i get it now, Thanks

Comment: @SalahEddineMakdour -- You should initialize your member variables in the `Subject` default constructor.  `Subject s; std::cout << s.grade;` would produce undefined behavior, due to `s.grade` not being initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// the Subject class
class Subject {
    public:
        string name;
        float grade;
        int factor;
        
        Subject(){};
        
        Subject(string x, float y, int z){
            name = x;
            grade = y;
            factor = z;
        }
};

// get Input function declaration
vector<Subject> getInput(int num){
    
    // array of objects of type "Subject"
    vector<Subject> subArr;
    
    // a for loop to assign the array's elements
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        string name;
        float grade;
        int factor;
        
        cout << "what is the name of subject " << i+1 <<"? "<<endl;
        cin >> name;
        
        cout << "what is the grade of subject " << i+1 << "? "<<endl;
        cin >> grade;
        
        cout << "what is the factor of subject " << i+1 << "? "<<endl;
        cin >> factor;
        
        subArr.push_back(Subject(name, grade, factor));
    };
    
    // trying to return the subArr at last
    return subArr;
};

// main function
int main(){
    // get the number of subjects
    int numOfSubjects;
    cout << "how many subjects are there? ";
    cin >> numOfSubjects;
    
    // trying to receive the subArr from getInput call
    vector<Subject> subArr = getInput(numOfSubjects);
};
```